# facebook open graph preview thumbnail image is not showing all of a sudden

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I know this has been asked several times but i am really puzzled as this just stopped working for my new links last few days. All the old links that are cached just works fine.

I have my meta tags very neat. facebook debug tool does not report any error/warnings.

Here are my meta tags ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="820998487913242">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="param.krish.5">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="obtest.obkrish">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:site_name" content="Salefrog.in">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:type"     content="website">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" content="http://www.salefrog.in/register_fmp">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="Salefrog.in : Register as a Freelance Marketing Partner (FMP)">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:description" content="Register as a FMP. Join us. Get a FMP login and get paid as you earn credit points. More details in your login upon registration.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.salefrog.in/img/fmp-picture.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250">
<meta name="title" content="Salefrog.in : Register as a Freelance Marketing Partner (FMP)">
<meta name="description" content="Register as a FMP. Join us. Get a FMP login and get paid as you earn credit points. More details in your login upon registration.">
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.salefrog.in/img/fmp-picture.jpg">
</head></html>
```

Facebook debug tool tells me that it picks up an image but the image preview is not just there at all (looks to be hidden) as shown below.

[image]

When i click that "blank" space against the "og:image" , it opens up the image in a separate window so why does not it show up the preview image in the debug tool ?

I attempted changing the picture to different sized one's like 250x250, bigger etc. but nothing really helped. When i place one of the old cached images in the meta tag, it shows up that image. This tells me that old cached images are just fine but the newer images are not showing at all, for some reasons.

I tested using the link http://www.salefrog.in/register_fmp in the debug tool. If you guys can find some error, do let me know as it would really help me save time than i break my head to fix it all by myself.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem. It was due to the .htaccess which was blocking(or not letting the facebook ) to parse the image which was the reason that it threw a blank image , not showed any error.

**How i fixed or analyzed the whole problem ?**

Since there are no errors reported by the facebook debug tool and nothing seen in the apache logs, i suspected it could be that the tool itself does not sense any error with the whole process hence it must be something to do with the image itself OR something in-between.

Requests from facebook hits my webserver which has a .htaccess to redirect to a separate php that responds back only the meta tags , nothing else.

As there are no errors reported in facebook debug tool or in my webserver httpd logs, it could be two things that is causing the problem.

- Image itself (could be the location of the image or the image is
  corrupt or its size or aspect ratio or other format)
- facebook debug tool has a bug (very unlikely but cant rule out )
- (.htaccess) that does the redirection when the request comes from fb

As i have reasonably no doubt with the first two, i went to the 3rd item in the list.

I suspected the requests from fb is not fetching my images possibly due to the redirection happening for the "HTTP GET" to the image requests as well.

**SOLUTION**

I added the following line in the .htaccess just before the redirect so that all the image requests directly goes to the file, which just fixed the whole problem.

```
 ..
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(facebookexternalhit)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(img|css|jp?g|png|store_images|category_images|fonts|awesome|ttf|tif|custom_images)
 ..
```

I know in most cases it might be something to do with the errors in the meta tags or in the image itself. But, in my case , it was not both.

Hope this helps someone out there !!